# WinDbg can't find mfc90 version 9.0.30729.4148 symbols on msdl.microsoft.com

Tags: mfc, windbg, symbols

WinDbg can't find mfc90 version 9.0.30729.4148 symbols on msdl.microsoft.com

Where are those mfc symbols?

Some background info:

- I have a crash dump that I want to analyze in WinDbg.
- My symbol path contains http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
- The 9.0.30729.4148 version seems to be installed by some Windows update
- When a dump contains an earlier version of mfc90, it is located by WinDbg on the Microsoft symbol server with the same settings.
- When I use !sym noisy, the output for mfc90.dll contains:
  SYMSRV:  http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/mfc90.dll/4A596D4939c000/mfc90.dll not found
- The same thing happens on two different computers

The symbols are present on the server, but WinDbg can't get them.

Comment: Well, now I've found the symbols - in c:\windows\symbols. I just debugged the program in VC++ and looked at the modules, it had the same mfc version and had found the symbols in c:\windows\symbols. 

Still, the question remains - why aren't those symbols at msdl.microsoft.com?

I'm going to file a bug report at microsoft connect and see what they have to say.

Comment: Hm, it seems like Visual Studio (2008, SP1) can get the symbols from the microsoft symbol server, if I move them away from c:\windows\symbols. Perhaps I need to update WinDbg (mine's from feb 2009). Perhaps something has changed in the way the server works.

Comment: Now I've installed the latest WinDbg version, but it still can't load symbols for mfc90 9.0.30729.4148 from the MS symbol servers...

Does anyone know where I can report this bug?

Comment: Did you try the approach that hofingerandi explains below? That solved the problem in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar behaviour in Visual Studio; the symbols for MFC90.dll wouldnt load. Clicking on "Symbol load information" for mfc90.dll gave "No matching binary found".

I searched for the correct dll on my computer and found it at

```
C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC90.MFC_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4148_x-ww_a57c1f53
```

Note that of course this path only contains the dll, but not the .pdb-file.

Anyways, after adding this path to the symbol search path, Visual Studio is able to download the correct pdb-file from the Microsoft symbol server.

In case the required dll cannot be found locally, I suppose [ModuleRescue](http://www.debuginfo.com/tools/modulerescue.html) can help.

Comment: This answer actually sounds weird, but it worked perfectly fine for me. Thanks!